# Issue with changing each element in array with control flow statement

Tags: ruby

This is a portion of my code below, anyways, this is the only thing that is not working. I am puzzled.

```
def change_numbers_to_grade_points
 @course_grades.each do |grade|
   case
   when grade < 100 && grade > 93.99
     grade == 4.0

   when grade < 93.99 && grade > 89.99
     grade == 3.7

   when grade < 88.99 && grade > 86.99
     grade == 3.3

   when grade < 86.99 && grade > 82.99
     grade == 3.0

   when grade < 82.99 && grade > 79.99
     grade == 2.7

   when grade < 79.99 && grade > 76.99
     grade == 2.3

   when grade < 76.99 && grade > 72.99
     grade == 2.0

   when grade < 72.99 && grade > 69.99
     grade == 1.7

   when grade < 69.99 && grade > 66.99
     grade == 1.3

   when grade < 66.99 && grade > 59.99
     grade == 1.0

   when grade < 59.99 && grade > 0
     grade == 0.0
   else
     puts "Something went wrong with conversion!"
     puts
   end
 end
end
```

Comment: What is your code supposed to do, and how is it not working?

Comment: It is a GPA calculator. I ask the user for their grade out of 100 in their class, then I come to this where I convert the number into a grade point. All the input grades out of 100 are in an area, and I am trying to take each grade and put it through this set of control flows. But nothing converts!

Comment: What happens to grades that do not match any condition, for example `100` or `93.99`?

Answer (score 2):

`==` is equality. You want to use `=` for assignment.

eg:

```
when grade < 100 && grade > 93.99
  grade = 4.0
```

However that isn't the problem either, as you're not modifying any of the elements in the array you're iterating with the `.each` loop

Consider something like

```
@course_grades.size.times do |i|
   grade = @course_grades[i]
   if # something
      @course_grades[i] = #some new value
   end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

As the other user suggested, you should really be using `map!` because you want to replace the contents of the original array using the result of your `case`. And by the way, instead of using `lambdas` you could use `Ranges`. As follows:

```
 # Since your method is changing the contents of
 # an instance variable, the convention is that
 # your method ends with a bang (!)
 def change_numbers_to_grade_points!
    @course_grades.map! do |grade|
     case grade
     when 93.99..100
       4.0

     when 89.99..93.99
       3.7

     when 86.99..88.99
       3.3

     when 82.99..86.99
       3.0

     #...

     #An error is raised if something is wrong because of map!
      else
        raise "Something went wrong"
      end
    end
```